# How to use ORDER BY with 2 columns created by different aggregate functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to use SALESPERSON_CUSTOMER_REVENUE (salesperson's revenue for each customer) and total revenue by each salesperson in ORDER BY. Currently, I can only use only SALESPERSONPERSONID and SALESPERSON_CUSTOMER_REVENUE in ORDER BY statement.

```
SALES_ORDERS
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   SALESPERSONPERSONID    |      CUSTOMERID        |     ORDERID       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|              3           |            10          |      324371       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

SALES_ORDERLINES
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|   ORDERID    |    ORDERLINEID    |   QUANTITY   |   UNITPRICE    |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|   324371     |      10           |      32      |      100       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**My current query**

```
SELECT 
    ORD.SALESPERSONPERSONID,  
    ORD.CUSTOMERID,
    SUM(LINE.QUANTITY * LINE.UNITPRICE) AS SALESPERSON_CUSTOMER_REVENUE 
    
    FROM SALES_ORDERS ORD
        INNER JOIN SALES_ORDERLINES LINE
            ON ORD.ORDERID = LINE.ORDERID
                
    GROUP BY ORD.SALESPERSONPERSONID, ORD.CUSTOMERID
    ORDER BY ORD.SALESPERSONPERSONID, SALESPERSON_CUSTOMER_REVENUE DESC
```

**expected result**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| SALESPERSONPERSONID | CUSTOMERID | SALESPERSON_CUSTOMER_REVENUE |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|       3             |     10     |             3200             |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|       3             |     12     |             2200             |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|       1             |     2      |             2000             |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|       1             |     1      |             1200             |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|       2             |     3      |             3000             |
```

TLDR:
I want to sort salespeople by their total revenue and for each salesperson, I want to sort by revenue for each customer.

Please let me know your idea. Thank you!

Comment: Hello , please specify what database do you use ? Is it Oracle ? Is it SQLServer ? Also, please give us some data example. Like this: In table SALES_ORDERS I have this data(show us the data), in table SALES_ORDERLINES  I have this data(show us the data)... My queery returns this data(show us)... and I expect to get this data(show us)...

Comment: @VBoka I'm using PostgreSQL

Comment: Hello @HangNguyen, if you check this link: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=aa5795e309ab21621472567a316a6ead you will see a small simulation of your code. I personaly do not understand what is your problem here...

Comment: @Vboka I edited my question above. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are getting the same results because you are performing the exact same operation in each aggregate column. I think this would be a great use case for a [window function](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-window-functions/).

Since you want to get the results grouping bY different columns, PARTITION BY solves that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  ORD.SALESPERSONID,  
  ORD.CUSTOMERID,
  SUM(LINE.QUANTITY * LINE.UNITPRICE) OVER (PARTITION BY SALESPERSONID) AS SALESPERSON_REVENUE, 
  SUM(LINE.QUANTITY * LINE.UNITPRICE) OVER (PARTITION BY SALESPERSONID, CUSTOMERID) AS SALESPERSON_CUSTOMER_REVENUE 
FROM 
  SALES_ORDERS AS ORD
INNER JOIN 
  SALES_ORDERLINES AS LINE ON ORD.ORDERID = LINE.ORDERID               
ORDER BY 
  SALESPERSON_REVENUE DESC,
  SALESPERSON_CUSTOMER_REVENUE DESC
```

- You will see that column `SALESPERSON_REVENUE` will aggregate the operation `SUM(LINE.QUANTITY * LINE.UNITPRICE)` per salesperson
- And column `SALESPERSON_CUSTOMER_REVENUE` will aggregate the operation `SUM(LINE.QUANTITY * LINE.UNITPRICE)` per salesperson/customer combination.

Comment: Thank you @Aleix CC. Sorry I haven't used window functions much. Previously I created 2 tables and joined them to create the result, but your solution is so much succinct compared to mine.

Comment: Window functions are super useful, I recommend you to deep-dive on them. You'll start to realize how much stuff you can do with them ;D

Answer (score 1):

You can put window functions in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT ORD.SALESPERSONPERSONID, ORD.CUSTOMERID,
       SUM(LINE.QUANTITY * LINE.UNITPRICE) AS SALESPERSON_CUSTOMER_REVENUE     
FROM SALES_ORDERS ORD JOIN
     SALES_ORDERLINES LINE
     ON ORD.ORDERID = LINE.ORDERID               
GROUP BY ORD.SALESPERSONPERSONID, ORD.CUSTOMERID
ORDER BY SUM(SUM(LINE.QUANTITY * LINE.UNITPRICE)) OVER (PARTITION BY ORD.SALESPERSONPERSONID), 
         ORD.SALESPERSONPERSONID,
         SALESPERSON_CUSTOMER_REVENUE DESC
```

Note that there are three `ORDER BY` keys.  The middle one is important.  It handles the case when two sales persons have the same total revenue and ensures that the rows for each sales person remain together.